# How to achive maximum speed over Wi-Fi in home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, usb, nas

I'm trying to achieve possible max speed over Wi-Fi in home network.

I have keenetic extra KN-1711 router with HDD drive plugged in usb 2.0 port in front of my PC and 5Ghz Wi-Fi network up and running.

Writing speed from PC directly to connected via usb hdd is about 100-120 MB (megabytes) per second.
But, when sending files over WiFi using windows home network the speed dramatically changes to 10 MB/s.

So, the question is - what is the bottleneck in this process?

1. Regarding router specs, 5Ghz network can handle speed up to 120 MB/s (1120 mb/s) - correct?
2. Are there any limitations on router side, firmware?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/689017-how-do-i-increase-network-file-transfer-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KN-1711 has two major design flaws:

1. Its Ethernet ports are only capable of 100 Mbps Ethernet. Since its Wi-Fi is in the AC1200 speed class, it really needs gigabit Ethernet ports.
2. Its USB port is only capable of USB 2.0, which is ostensibly 480 Mbps, but in real use is often just 200 Mbps (24 MebiBytes/sec). Again, this is slow compared to AC1200 Wi-Fi. It needs a USB 3.x Gen1 SuperSpeed 5Gbps port to keep USB from being a bottleneck compared to its level of AC Wi-Fi support.

Its Wi-Fi capabilities are *decent*, but not great. AC1200 means it supports 2x2 MIMO 802.11ac with 80MHz-wide channels, for a max signaling (PHY) rate of 867 Mbps, which means about 600 Mbps (71 MebiBytes/sec) in the best real world conditions. So that's the answer to your question #1: It's 600 Mbps (71 MiB/sec), not the numbers you had guessed.

You didn't say what Wi-Fi client equipment you're using (on your PC/laptop or whatever), so I can't look up those specs, but be aware that your KN-1711 can't use Wi-Fi features that its client doesn't support, and the client can't use Wi-Fi features that your KN-1711 doesn't support; so the performance is limited to that subset of "go faster" features that *both* ends of the wireless link support. So part of your bottleneck could be the Wi-Fi capabilities of your client device's Wi-Fi adapter, and how that relates to what your KN-1711 supports.

Comment: Hi spiff, thanks for the detailed answer.

With regards to router's USB port it seems I should have writing speed around 200Mbps, don't I?

For data transferring I use native windows shared folder, like described here https://www.windowscentral.com/how-setup-and-manage-windows-10-homegroup-local-network but on router side.

Could you describe more about `Wi-Fi client equipment` and what options are best for such case?

Thanks in advance!